# python tkinter запуск "бесконечных" циклов

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Пишу программку в которой нужно запустить цикл который будет работать до тех пор пока его не остановят вручную. Не пойму как это реализовать. Попробовал через кнопку и через чекбокс, везде одна и та же проблема - программа перестаёт реагировать после запуска. вот упрощённый пример того что я хочу сделать. Помогите реализовать на уровне идеи, а дальше я надеюсь допилю сам.
первый вариант который я попробовал. Есть чекбокс. цикл проверяет его состояние и пока отметка стоит цикл перезапускается. Как только отметку снял, цикл стопает. Окно зависло, отметка даже не появилась а цикл работал и работал пока я не закрыл окно

```
def chek_cikl():
    while chesk_start.state():
        print(1)
        time.sleep(5)


var=IntVar()
chesk_start = ttk.Checkbutton(window, text='start', variable=var, command=chek_cikl)
```

второй вариант который я пробовал через кнопку старт, но там всё совсем плохо. Пытался сделать кнопку старт стоп, которая меняет глобальную переменную на значения 0 и 1 и цикл опирается на эти переменные что бы работать или нет.
В общем я в тупике на уровне идеи что пробовать ещё.

Answer (score 2):

Как всегда. Долго думал, искал ничего не мог найти. Стоило задать вопрос на форум, ответ нашелся. Вместо слипа надо использовать after и всё будет работать как я хотел